# Testing axios post request with jest enzyme

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, axios, jestjs, enzyme

I want to test axios post request. I am using Jest, Enzyme. I mocked axios and and expect the function setData to be called twice, but the tests failed. Why isn't the function called a second time, if the console output shows that the tests reach this block?
**package.json**

```
"@types/jest": "^26.0.14",
"jest-junit": "^12.0.0",
"axios": "^0.21.0",
"enzyme": "^3.11.0",
"enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.6",
"jest-react-hooks-shallow": "^1.4.2",
"typescript": "^3.9.7",
```

**requests.ts**

```
import axios from "axios";
import { v4 as uuid } from "uuid";
import store from "../store/store";
import { errorProcessing } from "./error-processing";
import { Response, ResponseError } from "./shared/common/response";
import { prepareData } from "../utils/data";
import { Graph } from "./shared/common/graph";
import { Method } from "../constants/methods";

const createJsonRpcPayload = <P>(method: Method, params: P) => {
  const id = uuid();
  const jsonrpc = "2.0";

  return { jsonrpc, id, method, params };
};

export const fetchData = <D, R, P>(
  method: Method,
  setData: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<Graph<D>>>,
  data: Graph<D>,
  params: P | {} = {},
): void => {
  const url = process.env.REACT_APP_RECSYS_API_URL || "";
  const payload = createJsonRpcPayload(method, params || {});
  const accessToken = store.getState().oidc?.user?.access_token;

  setData({ ...data, isLoading: true });

  axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = accessToken ? `Bearer ${accessToken}` : "";

  axios
    .post(url, payload)
    .then((response: Response<R>) => {
      if (response.status === 200) {
        const result = response?.data?.result;
        const errorCode = result?.errorCode;
        if (!errorCode) {
          console.log("result.data", result.data);
          setData({
            data: prepareData(method, result?.data) as D,
            name: result?.name,
            error: {
              type: "",
              text: "",
            },
            isLoading: false,
          });
        } else {
          throw { response };
        }
      }
    })
    .catch((error: ResponseError<R>) => errorProcessing(error, setData, data));
};
```

**requests.test.ts**

```
import { fetchData } from "../api/requests";
import axios from "axios";
import { Method } from "../constants/methods";
jest.mock("axios");

beforeEach(() => jest.clearAllMocks());

const mockedAxios = axios as jest.Mocked<typeof axios>;
const setData = jest.fn();
const graph = { name: "name", isLoading: false, data: [1, 2, 3], error: { text: "", type: "" } };

describe("fetchData", () => {
  test("good response", () => {
    mockedAxios.post.mockResolvedValue({
      status: 200,
      data: {
        result: {
          name: "name",
          data: [1, 2, 5],
        },
      },
    });
    fetchData(Method.RECSYS_STATISTICS, setData, graph);
    expect(setData).toBeCalledTimes(2);
  });
});
```

[image]

Comment: fetchData is doing something asynchronous (calling fetch) but your test doesn't take that into account. I'd suggest returning the promise chain from the function, that'll make if much easier.

Comment: The question here is are you calling the setData function twice? If you want to test for error you need to test it separately as it will just call only once.